# jQuery string replace with regex not working

Tags: jquery

String:

```
remove_old('pad3.jpeg','3')
```

jQuery:

```
var new_value = onchange_value.replace("remove_old(", "");
new_value = new_value.replace(")", "");
```

Expected Output:

```
'pad3.jpeg','3'
```

I want to remove remove_old(). Anyone can please tell me How can I remove this by using regex. Sorry for my weak English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
/\((.+)\)/
```

Broken down:

- `\(`  match a `(`
- `(` start matching group
- `.` any character
- `+` one or more of previous (any character, so at least one character)
- `)` close matching group
- `\)` match `)`

Then

`src.match(regex)[1]` takes the first match-group (inside the `()`).

```js
var src = "remove_old('pad3.jpeg','3')";
var expected = "'pad3.jpeg','3'";
var updated = src.match(/\((.+)\)/)[1];
console.log(expected==updated)
console.log(updated)
```